# Weird NumberFormatException that shouldn't come up?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

hello everyone well i have this code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ItemIdReader {
    public int id;
    public ItemIdReader(){

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("itemList.txt"));
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (true) {
                if (line == null)
                    break;

                String[] split = line.split(" - ", 2);

                String itemName = split[1];
                id= Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            }
        } catch (IOException i ) {

            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

and when i try to output the id , i get this error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at ItemIdReader.<init>(ItemIdReader.java:19)
at Launcher$UI.lambda$new$0(Launcher.java:25)
at Launcher$UI$$Lambda$1/455659002.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

here is the .txt file im reading from :

```
1 - Toolkit
```

and here is the println :

```
            ItemIdReader newF= new ItemIdReader();
            System.out.println(newF.getId());
```

As you can see i already made the value id an integer however i still get that it says its a string when i try to output it, thanks.

Comment: I get no exception. But you have an endless loop. Line will never set again.

Comment: `ItemIdReader` is not in the stack trace, the problem is somewhere else... and you have an endless loop as everyone said

Comment: You have Infinite loop ...

..Oh you have Infiniteloop....


......No you have Infinite looop....!!!!

"Question is about `NumberFormatException`"

Nooo... You have infinite loop.... :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you didn't have this exception, you would have an infinite loop.

My guess is that you have a hidden character, probably a BOM, at the beginning of your file. Confirm it by dumping every char as an integer, and if it's confirmed, then reopen your file with an editor and make sure to save it without BOM.

```
for (char c : split[0].toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println((int) c); 
}
```

Comment: when i try to do the foreach you provided, it tells me foreach is not applicable for split[0] (java.lang.String)

Comment: try:  for (char c : split[0].toCharArray()){

Answer (score 0):

If you move the readln inside the loop it works fine

```
while (true) {        
String line = br.readLine();

            if (line == null)
                break;

            String[] split = line.split(" - ", 2);

            String itemName = split[1];
            id= Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an infinite loop!
you should read the line again inside the while. This code is similar to you want to do and it works for me:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException{
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("itemList.txt"));
       String line = br.readLine();
        while (true) {
            if (line == null)
                break;
            String[] split = line.split(" - ", 2);
           String itemName = split[1];
           int id= Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
           System.out.println(id);
           line = br.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) is right. There is indeed a Byte Order Mark, it is copied into you error message.

You could read you file using [BOMInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) to avoid this.